# Dimension reduction methods for images

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, matlab, dimensionality-reduction

I am trying to reduce the dimensions on an a set of images using *Matlab Toolbox for Dimensionality Reduction*. Problem is: I know very little about dimension reduction. So am trying each one by trial and error, passing the data set to the function. I have tried 6 so far, PCA was returning a matrix with a complex number. And the others was frozen matlab. What Image reduction methods is suitable for images?

Comment: Off-topic: Would be better-suited at http://dsp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Why do say that? Cause I was wondering if it better suited for Cross Vaildated

Comment: Because your question seems to be closer to "how does PCA work?" rather than a programming question.

Comment: I really meant to ask. Which dimension reduction method should I use on images... Will edit to be more actually.

Comment: What do you aim via dimensionality reduction? PCA is good for maintaining reconstruction error (that is the best low rank approximaton in terms of l2 reconstruction error), but is that really what you want?

Comment: Trying to recognize patterns on clothes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to implement something like [eigenfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface), so first of all take a look at the article. Normally you need to get eigenvectors either with **PCA** or with **SVD**. However, if you need really low resources use, take a look at [Random Projection](http://users.ics.tkk.fi/ella/publications/randproj_kdd.pdf) method.

Comment: Here note, that SVD may be used as one possible implementation of PCA, but PCA has other implementations too and I don't know which on is used in Matlab toolbox.